# Streaming videos in iOS 4 using MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to stream a *.m3U8 video file over http streaming in iPhone.prior to iOS 3.2,it used to play flawlessly on iPhone.
But with latest changes to the MoviePlayer APIs, I am unable to stream this file on iOS4 devices.

I am now using MPMoviePlayerViewController object to play this file, but every time I get the error "Error code=2. File could not be played".
Error description is very insufficient and Apple's sample code for MPMoviePlayerViewController is obsolete.
Please help me out with the solution or give some reference to the sample code or working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The controller:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet PlayerView *playerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayerItem *playerItem;

// Use a HTTP URL, example: http://192.168.2.103/video.m3u8
-(void) setUpPlayer:(NSURL*) url {
    AVURLAsset *anAssest= [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil];
    [anAssest loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVKeyValueStatus status = [anAssest statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
        if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) {
            self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:anAssest];
            self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
            self.playerView.player=self.avPlayer;
            [self.avPlayer play];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"The asset's tracks were not loaded:\n%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

The view:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PlayerView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer* player;
@end

#import "PlayerView.h"
@implementation PlayerView
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}
- (AVPlayer*)player {
    return [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] player];
}
- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player {
    [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
}
@end
```

Something like that :P You should create the m3u8 with Apple's mediafilesegmenter command, but probably it will work anyway.

Comment: It only plays audio and not the video.Moreover, it doesn't provide the player interface.the audio keeps on playing in the background.  Can MPMoviePlayerController not be used for http streaming?